# KML problems on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

If I upload my KML file, which contains polygons and pins, to Google Maps, then most of the polygons are missing (see below).

[image]

To try and address this, I pasted the kml url to the Google Maps search bar and all of the polygons are now shown on the map but all the pins are missing (see below).

[image]

The KML file can be downloaded from **[here](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=2&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=207719308852398276835.0004ec1545f24164d77e8)**.

What should I modify in the KML source to have all polygons and pins in the same map?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is `outerBoundaryIs` in the KML

*"KML allows you to create Polygons with holes by designating an outer and inner boundary"*

Google Earth Supports this but **Google Maps API will not support** this data type. It has to to be single Polygon (not multiple-part or donut polygons).

source:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kml-support-getting-started/fg62ALm4YUU

Answer (score 0):

How did you create your kml? According to the Galdos KML Validator (http://kmlvalidator.com/validate.htm), your kml file is not valid:

> Unable to read content from the file. Is this one of the supported
>   file types?

However in my PC (ie. Google Earth) it displays correctly (apparently):

[image]

and same area without it:

[image]